# RodCutting and learning Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I tried to learn dynamic programming going from recursion to memoized version with the RodCutting problem: Returns the best obtainable price for a rod of length n  and price[] as prices of different pieces.

Have you any suggestions on the code (or the way to make test), i tried to keep as simple and generic to mimic on others similar problems (i could have  erase the n from input and calculate inside the function but it would confuse the solution).

```
"""
Inspiration of DP from: https://wellsr.com/python/optimizing-recursive-functions-with-python-memoization/
"""

def cutRod(price, n):
    """
    Returns the best obtainable price for a rod of length n
    and price[] as prices of different pieces
    """
    res = price[n-1] # One piece without cut
    for i in range(n-1):
        res = max(res,price[i]+cutRod(price,n-(i+1))) #i+1 cut
    return res

def cutRodMemo(price, n):
    """
    Returns the best obtainable price for a rod of length n
    and price[] as prices of different pieces
    """
    # 1.Define memo table
    memo = [None]*n
    memo[0] = price[0]
    # 2.Memoize recursive approach
    def cutRodAux(price,n,memo):
        if memo[n-1]:
            return memo[n-1]
        res = price[n-1]
        for i in range(n-1):
            res = max(res,price[i]+cutRodAux(price,n-(i+1),memo)) 
        memo[n-1]= res
        return res
    return cutRodAux(price,n,memo)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    f = cutRod

    class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        def test(self): 
            args = [(([10,24,30,40],4),48),
                      (([1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20],8),22)
                    ]
            for i,o in args:
                prices,size = i
                self.assertEqual(cutRod(prices,size), o)
                self.assertEqual(cutRodMemo(prices,size), o)
         
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't put tests in the same file as the main script
2. `f = cutRod` - f seems unused
3. Defining a function right in the middle of another one isn't very pretty. Move it up to the beggining or preferrably make a separate function altogether.
4. Removing `n` from the input would actually be a good idea as right now you are providing redundant information.